# función callback en otro archivo nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy usando el Api de twitter para recibir tweets, y necesito hacer un análisis al contenido previo a almacenarlo en una base de datos, para estoy usa una función con un callback que me haga el proceso, pero al momento de llamarla en mi archivo principal me sale un error en el parámetro, si creo la función en el llamado funciona, pero si lo creo en otro archivo deja de funcionar, aqui les pongo mi codigo de la función de tweets:

```
function queryTweet(criteria,callback){
    var jsonTweet= {};
    client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: criteria },  function(stream) {
        stream.on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);  
        });
    stream.on('data', function(data) {
          var sentiment ="";
          //query just spanish tweets
          if (data.lang=='es'){ 

                 //create tweet
                jsonTweet ={
                    "id": data.id,
                    "criteria": "",
                    "user":"@" + data.user.screen_name,
                    "date": data.timestamp_ms,
                    "name": data.name,
                    "text": prep(data.text),
                    "sentiment": "",  
                    "language": data.lang,
                    "coordinates": data.coordinates
                        }
                      // tweetCount++;
                    if (typeof callback === "function"){
                    return callback(jsonTweet);
                }
                    } // fin else 
     }); //close stream.on

  }); // close client.stream 

} // close query.tweet;
module.exports.queryTweet = queryTweet
```

callback:

```
function analyzeTweets(tweets){
    var tomorrow= n  +60 *60 * 24 * 1000;
    var diff = "";
    // var dailyTweets = 395;
    var diff = "";
    // var dailyTweets = 395;
    var dailyTweets = 100;
    console.log(data.text+ "\n contador:" + count);
    count ++ }
```

Llamado en app.js

```
var query = queryTweet.queryTweet;
var analyze = analyzeTweet.analyzeTweets;
var parameter = "query1";
var allTweets = query(parameter, analyze(data));
```

El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Comment: `data` esta declarado en app.js?

Comment: Disculpa, dime que api es esta, y si me permite, hacer stream, pero de un usuario en especifico, te lo agradezco.

Comment: Que tal es la api de twitter que la encuentras aqui: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public y estoy usando este paquete : https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter, espero que te ayude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás entendiendo mal cómo funcionan los callbacks. Tu función `queryTweets` recibe como segundo parámetro un callback, que es `analyzeTweets`. Hasta aquí está todo bien, pero luego, en lugar de pasar la función como tal, estás **ejecutándola** y pasando como parámetro `data`, la cual **no existe aún**.

Cuando la función `queryTweets` sea **ejecutada**, los tweets le serán pasados al callback, el cual será también ejecutado. Todo ésto pasa como vez en tiempo de ejecución, tú no tienes que pasar ningún parámetro al callback, de ésto se encarga la función principal. Tu código debe ser así:

```
const queryTweets = require('./queryTweets');
const analyzeTweets = require('./analyzeTweets');


let parameter = 'query1';
queryTweets(parameter, analyzeTweets);
```